# React how should be the like functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am building a blog site and there is a like functionality to like comments of users.

I get the comments and corresponding likers with an API call and assign them to state. If a user likes a comment, I call a POST request with the user_id and append the likers list in the database.

My question is; should I make a get request for the comments after like and assign them to the state and check whether the user_id is in the likers list,

OR should I append the state in the first place before/after put request to the database. **Without** the get request to assign the new likers list to the state.

I ask this question because it takes some time to get the new likers list and check whether the user_id is in the list. So after clicking the like button it takes 1-2 seconds to actually like the comment and make the heart red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET is not necessary after the POST. The purpose of having a response from the server is precisely so that you know that either a) your request/transaction went through successfully, or b) it failed and you need to handle why.

The best solution would be to update the state if and only if you get a 200 response code on the server from your POST request with the "like" information. Generally, it's best to update state only when you know that it's persisted in your database. Not doing so can lead to inconsistency if, say, the request failed and now you are showing a post is liked but as soon as they refresh, the "like" is gone (since it's not saved).

Comment: So you mean that, I should not get the likers from the database again but, check the response of the post request, if it is 200(successful) I should update the state and add the user_id in the list.

Comment: Correct. Think of the response from the server as either confirming that yes, everything has been updated correctly (200 response code), or no, something happened and it couldn't update (4xx or 5xx code). It's the responsibility of the *server*, not the *client* to make sure that when a 200 code is returned that it was actually properly inserted into the database. Doing a GET request for confirmation is "leaking" that responsibility.